# Java - Formatting fields on entire form

Tags: java

New to Java...creating basic forms for practice.  I have a form with 10+ text boxes, that I want formatted to turn Cyan when user enters the field, and return to white when leaving the field.  If the text is edited, it will turn to red to show user both which field they are in and that they have edited text.

The code I have is working, however, must I duplicate this Focus Listener and Modify Listener code for every text box, or is there a way to set this a "default" for all text boxes on the form?

```
text_8 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text_8.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {            @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            text_8.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
        }
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            text_8.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                    text_8.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));                   
                }
            });
            text_8.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        }
    });
    text_8.setBounds(10, 341, 76, 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way would be to extract these listeners into separate variables and then just add to every components you want...

Try something like this:

```
private static class MyListeners implement ModifyListener extends FocusAdapter
{
   @Override
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
   {
      final Text t = (Text) e.source;
      t.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
      t.addModifyListener(this);
   }
   @Override
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
   {
      final Text t = (Text) e.source;
      t.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
      t.removeModifyListener(this);
   }
   public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)
   {
      final Text t = (Text) e.source;
      t.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));                   
   }
}
private final MyListeners myListeners = new MyListeners();

...

text_8 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text_8.addFocusListener(myListeners);
text_8.setBounds(10, 341, 76, 21);
```